# OCaml - Pattern matching with list reference in a tuple

Tags: functional-programming, pattern-matching, ocaml, ml

is there a cleaner way of doing this? I'm trying to do pattern matching of a

`(a' option * (char * nodeType) list ref`

the only way I found was doing this :

```
match a with
| _, l -> match !l with
  | (c, n)::t -> doSomething
```

Wouldn't there be a way to match `a` with something else like ...

```
match a with
| _, ref (c,n)::t -> doSomething
```

... or something similar? In this example it doesn't look heavy to just do another match with, but in the real case it can somewhat be...

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `ref` type is defined as a record with a mutable field:

```
type 'a ref = {
    mutable contents : 'a;
}
```

This means that you can pattern match against it using record syntax like this:

```
match a with
| _, { contents = (c,n)::t } -> doSomething
```

Comment: (Wow, we are completely synchronized.)

Answer (score 13):

In OCaml a `ref` is secretly a record with a mutable field named `contents`.

```
match a with
| _, { contents = (c, n) :: t } -> (* Do something *)
```